# Removing a table from bucardo sync

Tags: postgresql, bucardo

I have two postgreSQL databases on two machines with Bucardo keeping them in sync. I have a particularly large table in the Postgres database which I don't want to have synced anymore, how do I tell bucardo to stop trying to sync it?

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to remove the table with the following command `sudo bucardo remove table <tablename>`

You can get the table name by doing `sudo bucardo list tables`
The output looks something like this:

```
15. Table: <tablename>            DB: db_metadata_remote  PK: id (int4)                            Syncs: <syncname>
1.  Table: <tablename>            DB: db_metadata_local   PK: id (int4)
```

Restart bucardo afterwards with sudo `bucardo restart` and the table should not get synced anymore

Answer (score 0):

```
bucardo remove sync <syncname>
```

You'll have to manually remove the triggers on the source table though

```
bucardo remove table <sourcetablename> --force
bucardo remove table <desttablename> --force
```

Comment: You don't need to remove the sync as it will stop the synchronization. Only remove the tables, and launch `bucardo validate all`, and then `bucardo reload`. Then review that the triggers have been removed from the table and if not drop it manually.